# How to curve the edges of menus?

Tags: 11.10, themes, customization, css, gtk3

I want to know if this is possible. Like the menu when you right click, if the edges can be curved. I don't like to see the square appearance.

Comment: did you mean menus with rounded corners?

Comment: Yeah, you have idea how?

Comment: @PaulMcDonald That should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menus with rounded corners are not possible yet with gtk+